# Set the height of a block depending of its content

Tags: jquery, offset

So, here is a [quick JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Axiol/CfB5s/) to demonstrate my problem.

Problem is, after having played with the `offset`, it happens that the `div#TL` should be shorter than before, but it isn't.

So, I'm looking for a way to reset the `div#TL` depending of the height it should have. Problem is, I can't know before which of the 2 columns will be the longest.

Comment: It looks long enough to me...

Comment: Yes it is. But this is not the problem. If you look at the result panel, there is a big empty space at the bottom. It is the original size of the `div#TL`, but it should be shorter. I'ld like it to be adjusted to its content.

Comment: Are you attempting some sort of masonry effect with these blocks? E.g. http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/basic-multi-column.html

Answer (score 0):

you won't change the height of relative/float/block by changing the top position of its relative/block/float children;it doesn't work like that

either you create 2 columns & won't even need to reposition anything either you set  the height/overflow after positioning the children

```
   $TL.css({

        overflow : "hidden",
        height : $TL.height()+math.Min($TL.find(".TLItem").map(function() {
                                            return   $(this).css("top");
                                               })
                                      )
       });
```

(me would change html structure)

Comment: It's getting late here, so I'll test it tomorrow. But, by curiosity, how would change the HTML structure?

Comment: 2 coontainers as child of tl and parent of items